# Why does db query hang forever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a ruby on rails app that's loosely based on railstutorial.org. I think all my users code is exactly the same at this point. I wanted to build a working system before starting modifications.
Now when I call users/1 the site hangs (chrome gives spinny circle going counter clockwise (not sure why, it's not still sending anything). It just literally never displays the page.
log/development.log:

```
Started GET "/users/1" for 72.204.113.219 at 2015-07-05 06:44:40 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]


Started GET "/signup" for 72.204.113.219 at 2015-07-05 06:45:04 +0200
```

As you can see the log just stops for 24 seconds before I request another page (which displays just fine and quickly).
app/views/users/show.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

I tried commenting out the gravatar hoping that it would solve things (same behavior before as after).
If I do a user signup it will get saved into the database without errors or problems, and if I try to save a user with the same email I have this in
log/development.log:

```
Started POST "/users" for 72.204.113.219 at 2015-07-05 06:45:21 +0200
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"gj37C+HvuG+betpHL9Cu3+qlQh+EZm/Tb4je7WBW2yX6DPNE/twTc/fcgHkQbjFhxBxIwWxaL5l2ph9NJiz1Jw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Alexandra Knopf", "email"=>"[FILTERED]@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('[FILTERED]@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 320ms (Views: 111.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

So it seems like the db is doing well (tried to db:reset, same behavior (except that I have to restart the db because those queries will actually still execute minutes and even hours later and prevent the db from dropping a table))
With that last part said, it would seem like a db issue, but I have no idea what would cause that or why.

Edits:
Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    debugger
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Projectz</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</body>
</html>
```

---

SOLUTION: **DO NOT** put debugger (byebug) in an app that gets run by phusion passenger in apache. It tries to display a rails console in the terminal and waits for input.... forever.

Comment: fixed, makes no difference (didn't think gravatar was the problem in the first place, just tried making sure (badly, apparently)).

Comment: Took it out, made no difference. rails console also had no problem with User.find(1): 2.1.2 :002 > User.find(1)
  User Load (0.6ms) .... etc.

Comment: What does your users controller look like?

Comment: Everything seems standard... any other files I should be pasting ? (put controller up there)

Comment: Hmm all looks very similar to the railstutorial code. It looks like the call to the database is being processed fine, it is when it trys to render the page that it is freezing. Could you post layouts/application.html.erb? Doesn't seem likely that it is the problem as it is rendering fine for your other pages but I don't know where else the problem could be

Comment: done. I think it's the same as railstutorial at this point (after 7.4.3) also rake test gives: 17 runs, 34 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out debugger in the show action. It is creating an breakpoint in your application. Alternatively if you open up your servers terminal window at this point where it is 'freezing' you will see some debug information, to allow the application to continue execution simply press CTRL-d in the terminal window.

Comment: commented it out, still have the same exact problem.  I'm running rails in phusion passenger in apache so I don't quite have the rails terminal.

Comment: Hmm alright well I'm stumped. Maybe try running it in WEBrick and see if it has the same problem?

Comment: Evidently it does not, page displays perfectly fine. Output from WEBrick: Started GET "/users/1" for 72.204.113.219 at 2015-07-06 11:27:36 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 150ms (Views: 71.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)

Comment: You're amazing. I uncommented the debugger line thinking that it wasn't the problem based on webrick working..... and then it showed the byebug prompt *in the terminal that was running rails server*. Long story short: I took out the debugger line, *restarted apache*, and it actually started working.

I'm thinking that byebug somehow was trying to show the prompt in the terminal that didn't exist and was waiting for it to be exited.